# How to modify external variables from inside powershell jobs?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0, powershell-7.2

If I have two or more `Start-Job/Start-ThreadJob`, how do I share variables among them?
I want to achieve the below scenario:

```
$a = 2
Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock { $a=$a+1 }
Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock {Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; Write-Host $a}
```

The above script should output 3 instead of 2.
Does powershell support any functionality to modify outside variables from jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use what are called Environment Variables.  The long discussion about how to use them is in [Help About_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2)  which you can read online by following the link.  It's also a help topic inside Powershell.

Information stored in enviorment variaables is visible to windows as well as to other jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and unfortunately, I couldn't get the environment variable to work. :(
I thought that saving the value to a file might work, but I can't say I liked that idea. A better solution that worked well for me was to save the value in the registry of the user running the script.
However, my breakthrough came when I found [this informative site explaining Environmental Variables](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-environment-variables/). When using the **PowerShell .NET Class**, I could set the scope of the environment variable. If I used the default scope "**Process**", it didn't work. But when I used the "**User**" scope, it worked like a charm, like this:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable','aaa','User')

# Set a value in the Registry within the job
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    # Set a value in the Registry
    Start-Sleep 3
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable','bbb','User')
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt 8; $i++) {
    $myVariableValue = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable','User')
    Write-Host "Value from Environment var. (i=$i sec) = $myVariableValue"
    Start-Sleep 1
}


[void](Wait-Job $Job) # #or Stop-Job $Job

[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TestVariable', '', 'User') #remove/empty TestVariable

Remove-Job $Job # Remove the job
```

The result was exactly what I needed:

```
Value from Environment var. (i=0 sec) = aaa
Value from Environment var. (i=1 sec) = aaa
Value from Environment var. (i=2 sec) = aaa
Value from Environment var. (i=3 sec) = aaa
Value from Environment var. (i=4 sec) = bbb
Value from Environment var. (i=5 sec) = bbb
Value from Environment var. (i=6 sec) = bbb
Value from Environment var. (i=7 sec) = bbb
```

As I understand, Start-Job is running in a different process; that's why $global:variableName or $Env:variableName doesn't work.

Comment: if you use `Start-ThreadJob` instead of `Start-Job` then updating a variable from within the runspace is quite easy